# Почему так работает константная ссылка?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    int a = 10;
    const long int &ref = a;
    a+=20;
    std::cout << ref;
}
```

Если написать, то вывод будет 10

```
int main() {
    int a = 10;
    const int &ref = a;
    a+=20;
    std::cout << ref;
}
```

А вот здесь уже вывод 30.

Причём если делать неконстантную ссылку другого типа, то появляется ошибка во время компиляции.

```
int main() {
    int a = 10;
    long int &ref = a;
    a+=20;
    std::cout << ref;
}
```

Можете пожалуйста объяснить, что здесь происходит.

Comment: Ну тогда и в заголовке тоже поправьте. Видимо вы замечаете, что на строке `const long int &ref = a;` создается ссылка на временный объект long int. А на строке `long int &ref = a;` она не создается, так ссылка на объект без const квалификатора не может биндиться ко временному объекту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда типы одинаковые (int, int), то модификация исходного объекта сказывается и на ссылочной переменной. А когда типы разные (int, long), то при использовании константной ссылки создаётся временный объект, который уже не связан с исходным объектом. Поэтому модификация исходного объекта уже не приводит к модификации того, куда указывает ссылка.

Comment: ... а ссылка на временный объект, может быть только **константной**. Или **r-value** `long int && ref`. Запись `long int &ref = r-value` приводит к несоответсвию типов.